# HSSFArea.java: The method getCells() is undefined for the type AreaReference

Tags: java, excel, import

Eclipse is giving me the following error:
The method getCells() is undefined for the type AreaReference.
It is weird because the exact same code does not give me an error on my other computer, which is running the same operating system and version of Eclipse.
On the working computer, it says the function (method?) is located at org.apache.poi.hssf.util.AreaReference, which is imported at the beginning. So it seems like it is not importing properly, any ideas how to fix this?? Below is the part of HSSFArea.java where the error is located.

```
AreaReference areaReference = getAreaForName(wb, name);
    if(areaReference == null) {
        return null;
    } else {
        CellReference[] cellReferences = areaReference.getCells();
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

It all points to different version of jar . (POI ??). How do you manage your dependency management... (maven??).

I will just make sure that the correct version of the jar is available as dependency, in both the project settings.

Comment: I am just using the standard version of Eclipse, so I don't think I'm using Maven (I don't even know what Maven is =/). Anyway, yes, it is using POI, and the .jar is showing up in the Referenced Libraries section... I tried updating the version of POI, but this didn't change anything. I'm pretty new to Java, are there other ways to check the dependency?

Comment: here is a copy of my code  - http://www.megaupload.com/?d=RY12WPZW- note that it is using the OptimJ plugin for Eclipse so you won't be able to run it unless you have it installed

Comment: Can you press control-o (I think, I use IDEA) and look for the class AreaReference. You will have to type in and when it gets listed, open it. (you will most probably not have decompiler). It will open up the skeleton of the code methods. just verify that the method getcells is available.

Comment: I think it is available... it's public. Here's a snippet of the code: public org.apache.poi.hssf.util.CellReference[] getCells();
    0  aload_0 [this]
    1  getfield org.apache.poi.hssf.util.AreaReference.cells : org.apache.poi.hssf.util.CellReference[] [5]
    4  areturn
      Line numbers:
        [pc: 0, line: 45]
      Local variable table:
        [pc: 0, pc: 5] local: this index: 0 type: org.apache.poi.hssf.util.AreaReference

Comment: in the package explorer there's a green circle next to getCells() : CellReference[].